# 五年ぶり、ぶり返す、。。。What does ぶり mean?

Tags: meaning, kanji, etymology

Where does the ぶり in 五年ぶり (Five years ago?) and ぶり返す come from, does it have a kanji, and what does it mean?

Comment: My guess is you probably first encountered 〜ぶり in お久しぶりですね！

Comment: Haha. I guess I did!

Answer (score 8):

#### Spelling

In reply to istrasci's final comment, the *buri* in *burikaesu* is the same 振る as *furu*, and can be spelled in kanji as 振り返す.  That said, the *buri* is more often spelled in kana to make the voiced reading explicit.

#### Phonology

Changing an *h-* or *f-* on the front to the voiced *b-* variant is common in the latter element of compounds (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku), explaining why *-fur-* changes to *-bur-* in compounds.

When the *fur-* is in word-initial position, the shift to voicing can imply some kind of pejorative meaning, as noted by a number of linguists.  From Laurence Labrune's [*The Phonology of Japanese*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ix9r6CbEl6IC) (2012), p.102:

> The voiced obstruents which appear word-initially in Yamato words come from the following sources.  First, one finds a number of cases which result from secondary voicing of an originally unvoiced obstruent, whose phono-pragmatic function is to introduce a pejorative or expressive connotation.

#### Semantics (Meaning)

振る *furu* is ultimately cognate with the *furu* in classical *furuu*, modern 震{ふる}える "tremble, shake, vibrate, quake".  The *furu* on its own can mean "wave, shake", but it also has a range of other meanings, a number of which imply "the movement of a thing as a whole".  That underlying sense might be where derived term 振り *furi* came to include meanings such as "likeness; kind; one's appearance, style, or behavior".

*-Buri* as the latter element in compounds derives from this *furi*, and can be found in words like 身振{みぶ}り "body language, how one moves, appearance", or 女振{おんなぶ}り "a woman's face or appearance".

When appended to a time-related noun or phrase, *-buri* again carries stronger connotations of "whole, entire", in terms of "the *whole* XX amount of time has passed".  三週間ぶり would mean "it's been three whole weeks [since ...]".  久しい literally means "eternal; a very long time."  久しぶり is thus often an exaggeration, similar to English "it's been forever!" even though the speaker and listener might have seen each other recently.

For the *buri* in *burikaesu*, the meanings given for this verb are generally negative, suggesting that the voicing is indeed pejorative.  Whereas *furikaesu* can mean simply "to turn something back", *burikaesu* means "to get worse again, as said of a previously improving situation."

Answer (score 1):

The `ぶり` in `5年ぶり` comes from the verb `振る` which is usually read `ふる`, but can also be `ぶる`.  The kanji is not often used (in my experience) in this context.  It means "shake" or "wave", but I'm not sure how that really plays into these time expressions.

As a verb ending (`〜ぶり`), it can mean "way of doing"; similar to `〜[方]{かた}`, but I believe more subjective.  Here, `振る` takes the meaning of "assume", "pretend", "put on", or "pose as".  For example, `高ぶる` means to be arrogant -- "assuming" a high position.  So you can see the verb ending comes from this.

> - 話し振り　→　Way of speaking →　One's (assumed) mannerisms of speech (subjective)
> - 話し方　→　Way of speaking　→　How to speak (methodically; objective)

As far as `ぶり返す`, I cannot tell from all the definitions in my dictionaries if this is the same `ぶり` or not, so I'll defer that question to someone else.