# What does ぶり mean when it is attached to question words?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, nuances

I already understood the nuances of ぶり that were presented here:
[ぶり](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16148/%E4%BA%94%E5%B9%B4%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8A-%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8A%E8%BF%94%E3%81%99-what-does-%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8A-mean)

But what does it mean when it is attached to question words like いつぶり or 何年ぶり？

I got recently this message 学校に行くのいつぶり？

How does that differ from a simple いつ？

Answer (score 5):

Well, they are quite different and the difference is not nuanced but pretty clearly shown.

> 学校に行くの(は)いつ？
> When are you going to school? (When is it that you will go to school?)

> 学校に行くの(は)いつぶり？
> When was the last time you went to school? (How much time has passed since the last time you went to school?)

Actually [@Eiríkr Útlendi gave a very good explanation in the answer you cited](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16153/30454) that's hard to improve on:

> When appended to a time-related noun or phrase, -buri again carries stronger connotations of "whole, entire", in terms of "the whole XX amount of time has passed". 三週間ぶり would mean "it's been three whole weeks [since ...]".